# why $(element) not works directly. but works in function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When i try to select any element which is the result of ajax call it don't get selected using `$(element)`
but when i try to select that element in any function it will selected

Example: if i select an element with id `change`.

`hello.php` is

```
<?php
 echo '<span id="change"> hello </span>';
?>
```

html in `main.php` is

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

and script in main.php

```
<script>
$.post("hello.php",function(r,s){$("#content").html(r)});
$("#change").css({"backgroundColor":"red"});
</script>
```

this script don't change the color of span , I know it will not work because at the time when 2nd statement is executed their was no element with id `change`,
and `$("#element")` can't find the element with id `change`

But when i try `$("#change")` in any function it will change the color of span.
for example if i use

```
<script>
$.post("hello.php",function(r,s){$("#content").html(r)});
setTimeout(function(){$("#change").css({"backgroundColor":"red"});},0);
</script>
```

Please note i set the delay time to 0 sec. But this works and change the color of span with id `change`. I mean now the `$("#change")` can find the element with id `#change`

and if i use $("#change") in ajax function then also it works.

```
<script>
 $.post("hello.php",function(r,s){$("#content").html(r)});
 $.post("example.php",function(r,s){$("#change").css({"backgroundColor":"red"});});
</script>
```

Can someone explain why this happen , why in other two examples `$("#change")` selects the element. even their is no delay in executing the function

Comment: Because first `a` in `ajax` means `ASYNCHRONOUS`

Comment: can u please explain.

Comment: Just to test use sleep() on php side and you will get totally different results. It is a race condition

Comment: @eisbehr you mean , when we selects the element using `$("#change")`  in a  function. its execution automatically delay little bit and  browser update the dom in mean time. am i right?

Comment: @eisbehr  I think my questions irritates you. sorry man but my understanding is very poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of your `post` command. The rest of the script doesn't get halted till the post get finished. Rather than that, it get's executed even though the `post` command is already under progress. What you do with the `timeout` function is that you delay the execution of the jquery selection by a fraction of time, and this gives the time for the `post` to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Is all about timing. When you get content from the server and you try to inject it in DOM, it will take a bit to render. When you use setTimeout with whatever value, you push the inner function in the event loop. The result is that it will be executed after minimum time that you specify - in your case 0, but only when the stack is empty. During this time, things are rendering in DOM and you get to have access to those elements. You should watch this video for a much better explanation of what is going on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ